# Insert data from wordpress to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am a newbie to wordpress. I have a form in one of the pages like this:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
 Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br> 
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

Now I need to store the values of textboxes to the mysql database.

Do I need to create a new php file? If so then where do I place it? What will be my php code for insertion?

Comment: yes you need one more file. but you've also stated that it's somewhere on wordpress. why don't you follow wordpress guide for creating custom forms? (https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** You have to load wp-configuration if you are use external file structure.

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

**Step 2:** Create a function insertuser() with or without argument.

```
function insertuser(){
//Write code here
}
```

**Step 3:** Check is form sumbitted or not if submit then process a variable for database operation purpose.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}
```

**Step 4:** If form sumbitted the use $wpdp object for database operation. You can find more details here

```
global $wpdb; // Global database variable
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

**Step 5 :** get value from $_POST and initalize into a variable and run function for insert.

```
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('lname' => $lname, 'lname' => $lname) );
```

**Complete Source Code**

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');


function insertuser(){

 if(){
  global $wpdb;
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('lname' => $lname, 'lname' => $lname) ); 

  }
  ?>
   <form action="" method="post">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
    Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
  </form>

  <?php

}

insertuser();
```

Comment: What about the database connection? How i can come to know that these values will be inserted to the same database i am using?

Comment: there is file called  wp-config.php that define current database.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.7\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\php-code-widget\execphp.php(27)` . when i tried your code

Comment: I went to that folder and i opened `execphp.php` in line 27 i have this code `eval('?>'.$text);`

Comment: No don't do anything with this just cut this folder and put outside plugins.this plugin conflict with your code

Comment: this is my url `http://localhost/wordpress-4.7/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=444&action=edit`

Comment: if i deactivate it? Then how can i do the insertion , Can you please explain the entire flow? i am still confused how to do all these things.

Comment: where are you doing coding??

Comment: Your database related issue is solve please create new thread for newquestion.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
   Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
   Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // use global variable for database opertation
        global $wpdb;
    // assign value that pass from form 
        $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname= $_POST['lname'];
    // call insert method of wpdb class 
    $wpdb->insert('table_name', array(
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname ' => $lname // ... and so on
    ));
}
```

Refer link for more details about database operations in wordpress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: please add some details

Comment: which details are needed?

Comment: i think there's need of more explanation for my code if you thinks there should be some more details then you should edit my answer and share your knowledge with me.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @RushilPachchigar The Code enters `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` even if i  didnt click the submit button

Comment: its not possible please check code if(isset($_POST['submit'])) condition are used to set for this issues

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your questions explains how new you are..!!

No worries, let me tell you some thing you can insert your data using PHP in same page or can also add a new page. The HTML form action attribute decides where the data will be sent and if it is blank it will be submitted to the same page.

You just try submitting to the same page first you get your grip and to insert data at MySQL you need to connect with MySQL first and insert query.

LIKE:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

Above code taken from - $servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Above code taken from - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Thanks

Comment: Its core php level insertion.
Wordpress does not use this type of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
// in your template file add this code
<? php
if (isset($_REQUEST['register'])) {
    do_action('form_data');
} ?>
< form method = "post" >
    Firstname: < input type = "text"
name = "fname" / > < br > < br >
    Lastname: < input type = "text"
name = "lname" / > < br > < br >
    < input type = "submit"
class = "button"
name = "register"
value = "Submit" >
    < /form>

// and add this in function.php
<? php

function form_data_func() {
    $fname = $_REQUEST['fname'];
    $lname = $_REQUEST['lname'];
    $userdata = array(
        'first_name' => $fname,
        'last_name' => $lname,
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
add_action('form_data', 'form_data_func'); ?>
```

//developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user refer this link for parameters i had shown you how to perform insertion function

Comment: please add description or some explanation

Comment: if you want to create new user in wordpress simple this is for creating(inserting) user

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/ refer this link for parameters i had shown you how to perform insertion function

Comment: please add this in your answer

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, you need to use "Action" to submit your data to backend.

**For Direct Form Submission:**

- **Hooks Used**

  ```
  // 'action_name' is your form_name or any, but specify uniquely.

  // For Authorized User.
  add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_action_name', 'call_back_function` );

  // For Guest User.
  add_action( 'admin_post_action_name', 'call_back_function` );
  ```
- **In Form**

  You must specify this inside of your Form.

  ```
  <form> ......
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="action_name">
  ...... </form>
  ```

  This tells wordpress to connect your form with corresponding **CallBack** Function

**For Ajax Form Submission:**

- **Hooks Used**

  ```
  add_action('wp_ajax_contact_form', 'action_name');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_form', 'action_name');
  ```
- **List item**

  You have to add another item, named as "**action**"

  **ex.**

  ```
   $.ajax({ 
   data: {action: 'action_name'},
   type: 'post',
   url: your_url,
   success: function(data) {
      // On Success
  }
  ```

  });

These all are the way to submitting form and manage data in wordpress.

In your **callback** function, you can receive data in **$_GET**, **$_POST** or **$_REQUEST** to receive data.

After, inset into database have multiple options,

- You can use Post to Customize and follow the native of wordpress.
  Study, how to [create post](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1jfqJjZbRAhWLsI8KHX2pCAkQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.wordpress.org%2Freference%2Ffunctions%2Fwp_insert_post%2F&usg=AFQjCNEBw7uJfc9p2Kx54pjogJ4CMZ_XQw&sig2=jlhX3spT_iEjJdLPTci9sg).
- If you manage less data, you can choose [add option](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwis-bubjZbRAhXFpo8KHUVnCVYQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FFunction_Reference%2Fadd_option&usg=AFQjCNG278hVk9RFX87jHnVjPbxi6sY6Vw&sig2=zfwCGvY6wlIMgua_CSRlVQ&bvm=bv.142059868,d.c2I)
- If you need except this, you need create new table and follow core database management with wordpress instances. Then study these [WPDB](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi12erOjZbRAhXFK48KHVAXAQsQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FClass_Reference%2Fwpdb&usg=AFQjCNFYrPveN1qvqPwhISTmWlg4FFnX_w&sig2=JnDk0WzWefMSsUwY8gri0Q&bvm=bv.142059868,d.c2I) and [Table Creation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjItvLdjZbRAhXKNo8KHUk6BQwQFggZMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodex.wordpress.org%2FCreating_Tables_with_Plugins&usg=AFQjCNEzv5JBHHkzHhUK87sQMDMavQrvdw&sig2=mkUibfbVOdcsr7I6VidDcA&bvm=bv.142059868,d.c2I&cad=rja).

  Have a Joy With Wordpress...
   Thank You !